# Linking Play Developer Console to Google Wallet Error

Tags: android, google-play, android-pay

I've a major  issue with linking my Play Developer Console to Google Wallet. I've already search the Google Help for any solution and didn't find one. The problem is, that Error message appears after hitting “Set up a merchant account now” button in my Google Play Android Developer Console (Settings/Account Details). After that another screen pops out with an error:

> Oops! An error occurred while processing your request.

Regardless of any steps I've done such as changing to a different browser(Firefox to Chrome and back), clearing cache&cookies and so on... nothing is working.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should contact the Google support

Comment: I've done that in the first place but it's almost three days since I've send first email to Google. Waiting is so annoying and frustrating - I've my schedule and now everything is suspended.

Answer (score 0):

Any resolution yet? 
I just encountered the same issue. Also no followup from google teams.

A possible solution I am looking into is to use an alternative payment system such as http://www.zooz.com/

Comment: After almost four weeks since my first post here Gooogle manage to repair “some technical issues ” Hurey!
Three weeks ago I was informed by one member of the Google Checkout Team that “engineering team is working to resolve it as quickly as possible” and that they will inform me when “they will arrive at a resolution” But non of this happened.

Comment: Few days ago I accidentally discover, that everything is working properly and that linking Wallet with Dev Console is possible. What a surprise that was!!! But hey? Isn't that weird or something? 
My advice is: contact Google Checkout Team via Google Help about that issue. They will answer You byt it will take some/long time till they fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem a few days ago. After exchanging several emails with the service, they didn't know to tell me what happened, only they made me waste time. Then I started to fill the form on the Wallet account to avoid having to write every time I tried to link the accounts, and in this form itself is run the Javascript and I notice that my address could not be longer than 64 characters... I wrote a short version and I got my accounts linked.

In short, **if you can not link your Google Play and Google Wallet accounts, check the size of your inputs**, Javascript alerts dont work fine.

BTW: Outside USA could also be the fault of the VAT-ID, try to leave it empty.