# sign up google merchant account

Tags: android-pay, merchant-account

I need some advice on setting up merchant account in google.

When I try to set up merchant account, account signing up page shows me an error.
The error code is shown as "An error occurred {"type":"PLATFORM_ERROR", "payload":"0"}"

I've tried to resolve this issue with Google support team, but they keep sending me general information and manual..
Please give me suggestions on this issue. (I already finished developing my commercial application, but can't set the price because of this issue. )

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

What I did to resolve it was to flush the browser cookies, history and cache. After that, I opened a new browser tab and logged in to my **Google Wallet** account (the one I set up previously to BUY apps on the play store). As I was logging in, I noticed there was some error but it quickly resolved itself - I successfully logged in and could see what I previously bought.

After that, I closed and re-opened my **Google Dev Console**, and tried to setup a Merchant Account again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem and I finish solved changing my address length, uou can't use more than 64 characters. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21412790/2359141

Answer (score 0):

- clear cache and everything by using  <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>
- keep only one tab
- Select proper product type , I selected Computer software its worked for me
- Do sign out and  login in wallet google

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

You just have to let the VAT number empty during registration, fill it later.

It worked for me.

Comment: please add more information like code example for your answer.

Comment: No other info necessary, just leave the VAT field empty and the error disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I got the payload error as well, what resolved my problem was changing my PO Box address to a  physical address. Google chat support figured it out.